# Sendinblue attachment in Python

Tags: python, smtp, sendinblue

Gmail recently changed its security settings and [disabled the "less secure apps" option](https://wpmailsmtp.com/gmail-less-secure-apps/). My attempt to send emails with the Python module smtplib got blocked. So I chose a SMTP mailer, sendinblue. After setting up sendinblue, I'm able to send emails again, but I fail to include images that are stored locally. The email only contains an icon of the missing image. A [solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340866/sendinblue-attachment) has been proposed in php, but I am not able to apply it in Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint
import base64

with open('MyPlot.png', 'rb') as fin:
    data = fin.read()
    base64_data = base64.b64encode(data)

configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'my_api_key'   
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.TransactionalEmailsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))

subject = "Weekly Report"
html_content = "<html> Here is your weekly report <img src=base64_data alt='Report'/> </html>"
sender = {"name":"Sender","email":"sender@gmail.com"}
to = [{"email":"receiver@gmail.com","name":"FirstName LastName"},
      {"email":"receiver@gmail.com","name":"FirstName LastName"}]
reply_to = {"email":"replytome@gmail.ca","name":"FName LName"}
send_smtp_email = sib_api_v3_sdk.SendSmtpEmail(to=to, reply_to=reply_to, html_content=html_content, sender=sender, subject=subject)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.send_transac_email(send_smtp_email)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling SMTPApi->send_transac_email: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: I figured out there is a way to continue using Gmail with the Python smtplib module. One must activate the double factor identification and then produce a [Google application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you. I added that you need to .decode the encoded string of the png file and the attachment element in the .SendSmtpEmail function.

```
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
import base64
from pprint import pprint

filename = "MyPlot.png"

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
                        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(file.read())
                        base64_message = encoded_string.decode('utf-8')

configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'my_api_key'

api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.TransactionalEmailsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))

subject = "Weekly Report"
html_content = "<html> Here is your weekly report </html>"
sender = {"name":"Sender","email":"sender@gmail.com"}

to = [{"email":"receiver@gmail.com","name":"FirstName LastName"},
  {"email":"receiver@gmail.com","name":"FirstName LastName"}]

attachment = [{"content":base64_message,"name":filename}]

send_smtp_email = sib_api_v3_sdk.SendSmtpEmail(to=to, attachment = attachment, html_content=html_content, sender=sender, subject=subject)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.send_transac_email(send_smtp_email)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling SMTPApi->send_transac_email: %s\n" % e)
```